# I am trying to import ImageprocessingLibrary and add its dependency to my project, but I am getting "Could not get unknown property 'sdk'"

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

> Could not get unknown property 'sdk' for project ':ImageProcessingLibrary' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Error comes in this portion of gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion project.sdk
    minSdkVersion project.minSdk
    ndk {
        moduleName "hello-jni"
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
    }
    versionCode project.versionCode
    versionName project.versionName
}
```

Comment: What is error in logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the codes inside of defaultConfig like below:

```
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName '0.0.0.1'
```